# Trigger an audio element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

I'm making a drum machine, and so far I've been able to generate the grid with all the sounds(they're all the same for now, but I'll change it later), but I'm having trouble implementing my `playAudio` function. I logged my props and I saw that the information is being passed, but my function is not working very well. Here's the code:

App component

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import sounds from "./Sounds";

import DrumsGrid from "./DrumsGrid";

export default function App() {
  const playAudio = audio => {
    audio.play();
  };

  const mapped = sounds.map(sound => (
    <DrumsGrid src={sound.src} id={sound.id} handleClick={playAudio} />
  ));

  return <div className="App">{mapped}</div>;
}
```

DrumsGrid

```js
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";

function DrumsGrid(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="grid-element" onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.src)}>
      {props.id}
      <audio src={props.src} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DrumsGrid;
```

Sounds

```
const sounds = [
  {
    id: 1,
    src:
      "https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(SINGLE%20HITS)/Kicks/24[kb]bonger-kick.wav.mp3"
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    src:
      "https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(SINGLE%20HITS)/Kicks/24[kb]bonger-kick.wav.mp3"
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    src:
      "https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(SINGLE%20HITS)/Kicks/24[kb]bonger-kick.wav.mp3"
  },

  {
    id: 4,
    src:
      "https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(SINGLE%20HITS)/Kicks/24[kb]bonger-kick.wav.mp3"
  },

  {
    id: 5,
    src:
      "https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(SINGLE%20HITS)/Kicks/24[kb]bonger-kick.wav.mp3"
  },

  {
    id: 6,
    src:
      "https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(SINGLE%20HITS)/Kicks/24[kb]bonger-kick.wav.mp3"
  },

  {
    id: 7,
    src:
      "https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(SINGLE%20HITS)/Kicks/24[kb]bonger-kick.wav.mp3"
  },

  {
    id: 8,
    src:
      "https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(SINGLE%20HITS)/Kicks/24[kb]bonger-kick.wav.mp3"
  },

  {
    id: 9,
    src:
      "https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(SINGLE%20HITS)/Kicks/24[kb]bonger-kick.wav.mp3"
  }
];

export default sounds;
```

Comment: Did my answer help @Gabriel?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to answer you yesterday, thanks for the help

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `Audio` instance like this:

```js
const playAudio = audio => {
    const audioToPlay = new Audio(audio);
    audioToPlay.play();
};
```

And here is a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-golick-7e6nm